# Handling Hindi language in java

Tags: java, hindi

I have a link "http://bkwsu.org/thoughtText?lang=hi" from which I retrieved json data from which I extracted the 'text' which is in Hindi then in java. Then I tried to post this hindi text to fb page.Now the trouble is when I post the data to fb page it displays some gibberish. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import com.restfb.*;
import java.net.*;
import com.restfb.json.*;
import com.restfb.types.*;
public class MurliPost
{
    public static void main(String args[])throws Exception{
        String temp1="",temp = "";
        URL u=new URL("http://bkwsu.org/thoughtText?lang=hi");
        HttpURLConnection uc=(HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
        uc.setDoOutput(true);
        uc.setDoInput(true);
        uc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/534.29 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/12.0.733.0 Safari/534.29");
        uc.setRequestProperty("Connection","keep-alive");
        uc.setRequestProperty("Accept","text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml");
        uc.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language","en-US,en;q=0.8");
        uc.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset","ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3");
        uc.setRequestMethod("GET");
        uc.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(uc.getInputStream()));
        while ((temp=br.readLine())!=null){temp1+="\n"+temp;}
        String murli=temp1.substring(temp1.indexOf("'text':'")+8,temp1.indexOf("',\n'topic':"));
        murli=murli.replace("\\r\\n\\r\\n","\n\n");
        murli=murli.replace("\\r\\n","\n\n");
        murli=murli.replaceAll("[ \t]+", " ");
        Date date=new Date();
        murli=String.valueOf(date.getDate())+"/"+String.valueOf(date.getMonth()+1)+"/"+String.valueOf(1990+date.getYear())+"\n\n"+murli;
        System.out.println(murli);
        DefaultFacebookClient facebookClient=new DefaultFacebookClient("your access token goes here");
        JsonObject j=facebookClient.fetchObject("me/accounts",JsonObject.class);
        JsonArray acc=j.getJsonArray("data");
        for(int i=0;i<acc.length();i++) 
            if(acc.getJsonObject(i).getString("name").equals("Brahma Kumaris")) {
                DefaultFacebookClient facebookClient1=new DefaultFacebookClient(acc.getJsonObject(i).getString("access_token"));
                String posturl=acc.getJsonObject(i).getString("id")+"/feed";
                FacebookType publishMessageResponse=facebookClient1.publish(posturl,FacebookType.class,Parameter.with("message",murli));
                System.out.println("success");
                break;
            }
    }
}
```

So how do I handle this issue in java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should specify an encoding when instantiating the InputStreamReader, otherwise the default system encoding is applied on the output of the GET request, and if it doesn't match the encoding returned in the response this will corrupt the characters.